# %timeit instrucción mágica, loops each?

Tags: python, algoritmos

Tengo dos scripts y quiero evaluar el rendimiento de cada uno para decidir cuál es mejor. Para ello, hago uso del comando mágico %timeit y obtengo los siguientes resultados:

**1r script**

```
%timeit funcion_1(a)
875 ms ± 24.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**2ndo script**

```
%timeit funcion_2(a)
666 µs ± 37.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

En base a los resultados, me hace dudar el "1 loop each" o "1000 loops each". A qué se refiere? A primera vista diria que el 2ndo script es mejor ya que requiere menos tiempo sin embargo, no sé si ese factor debería multiplicarlo por 1000 y el primero por 1, en ese caso ya no seria mejor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El tiempo que imprime es lo que tarda, en promedio, cada ejecución individual de la función. Por tanto, la segunda función es 3 ordenes de magnitud más rápida que la primera.

Para explicar el número que va antes de `loops each`, este valor te indica cuántas veces iteró el comando en cada repetición para obtener la estadística (promedio y desviación estándar). Son parámetros que le puedes pasar a la instrucción:

Por ejemplo,

```
%timeit -n 250 -r 7 funcion_2(a)
```

La estadística se *calcula* haciendo `r` repeticiones de `n` veces cada una.

Para obtener números confiables, es bueno hacer ciclos con suficientes `n` y repetirlos al menos unas cuantas veces.

En otras palabras, un `n` muy bajo es, estadísticamente, menos confiable.

Dado que tu no estás pasando ningún parámetro, `timeit` hace pocas repeticiones de la función más tardada y muchas de la función menos tardada, para devolverte el resultado de ambas en un tiempo razonable; por lo que veo, unos 5 a 6 segundos cada una.

Cuando escribe su salida, incluye el texto `r runs, n loops each`. Sugiero que repitas el cálculo de la primera bajando el número de repeticiones y subiendo `n`, teniendo en cuenta que tarda 875ms en promedio, un `n` = 10 y `r` = 3, tardará aproximadamente 30 * 0.875 = 26.25 segundos en retornar.

Si puedes esperar un poco más, mejor:

```
%timeit -n 10 -r 3 funcion_1(a)
```